# HTML table column align right

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with 3 columns. I want that the third column is aligned to the right of the upper element and the other 2 columns to the left, like this:

```
(left column) (middle column)                                      (right column)
```

Is there a way to do this via CSS or something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `width:100%` on the table and the middle column.

Comment: You could also set width:100% on the last column's style and td align="right" on the last column. Then you can insert more columns in the middle while the spacing still works.

Answer (score 6):

> `<td style="text-align:right;">data1</td>`

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do what you want. The most basic is to change the alignment directly in the tag

```
<td align='left'>data1</td><td align='right'>data1</td><td align='left'>data1</td>
<td align='left'>data2</td><td align='right'>data2</td><td align='left'>data2</td>
....
```

If you need to change something else (CSS style) you could create a class like `.firstColumn` and `.secondColumn` on each `<td>`.

I tried to change directly the column, but that doesn't work (*[HTML table colgroup element is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658693/html-table-colgroup-tag-not-working)*).

Comment: Is that still supported?