# Table <colgroup> min-max-width ignored

Tags: html, css

Having this http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/EcU4x/

For the 1st column:

```
min-width: 100px;
max-width: 200px;
```

But if minimize browser window, 1st column width is getting less than 100px.

Need to have col widths in a range 100-200px.
Any workaround?

Comment: Why are you combining inline styles with CSS? You should move all your inline styles into your CSS as otherwise this will be a pain to maintain in the longrun.

Comment: this is just a quick simulation on jsfiddle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tried to remove

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

from table style, and that seems to make col have a min-width...

http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/mGgZ9/

Comment: In 2020 this does not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384205/5397695

Answer (score 0):

Do changes like this

```
<col style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 200px;">
<col style="min-width:75px;">
<col style="min-width:200px;">
<col style="min-width:auto;">
<col style="min-width:90px;">
```

set the min-width CSS property to define a minimum width for all the cells. This min-width represent the point at which the browser will add scroll bars rather than resizing the elements on the page.

Comment: tried that, but no effect. If remove "table-layout:fixed;" from table style => that works