# colgroup min-max-width not executed by Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, css-tables

I cannot use max-min width with colgroup even after removing table layout:fixed being removed.
Can anyone provide a workaround for Chrome? It works fine for Firefox.
Reference from 
[Table <colgroup> min-max-width ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940958/table-colgroup-min-max-width-ignored)

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50169

help